# Stripe default card in checkout

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Is there a way to fill fields in a Stripe checkout page when customer comes back? I've tried to set default payment method for customer with webhooks (payment_method.attached) but this default credit card won't show up during checkout. Instead Stripe creates new payment method for the customer every time he pays. It's strange to have dozen of exactly the same credit cards in a Stripe dashboard. Here is my current code:

```
const checkout = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    cancel_url,
    success_url,
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "payment",
    customer: stripeCustomer,
    client_reference_id: stripeCustomer,
    metadata: {
        //...
    },
    line_items: [{
        price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            product_data: {
            name: packetDisplayName,
            },
            unit_amount: packetPrice,
        },
        quantity: 1
    }]
})
```

I later use session id to redirect to checkout then perform few operations in a webhook endpoint

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout does not currently support using Payment Methods already attached to the provided Customer.

More broadly, there is not a concept "default" payment method for one-time payments for a customer, [only for invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method).

If you already have a known Customer and an attached payment method, you also have the option of [creating the payment yourself](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session), directly, using those details.

Comment: I checked with Stripe and this is still the case. Seems crazy we can't use a payment method to prefill checkout just because it was created by a different Stripe component. Stripe elements in my case. It was suggested I look at link but I will try this at a later date. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/link-card-element I have raised a feature request with Stripe. I recommend others do the same. https://support.stripe.com/contact

Answer (score -2):

try its work for me in Node.JS

For **add card** in node js

```
let card = await stripe.customers.createSource(customerid, {
        source: token
    });
```

Make card as **default card**

```
let updatecard = await stripe.customers.update(customerid, {
        default_source: card.id
      });
```

you can replace card.id if you just want update card only